# Using ReactDOM as an independent engine?

Tags: react-dom

In [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/11/20/face-off-virtual-dom-vs-incremental-dom-vs-glimmer/) it mentions using Facebook's ReactDOM as an independent engine; using it without React components. But I'm not finding any documentation on how this could be done.

Is this possible?

Is there any documentation as to what to feed ReactDOM.render, if not React components?

Thanks.